# KNN as Feature Engine - Tie back to base dataset after SMOTE

Tags: r, machine-learning, knn, ensemble-learning, smote

I want to use '[KNN as a Feature Engine](https://github.com/gedeck/practical-statistics-for-data-scientists/blob/6e9eae48a367bc801670fcd75747ded77b696067/R/code/Chapter%206%20-%20Statistical%20Machine%20Learning.R#L93)' as described in O'Reilly's [Practical Statistics for Data Scientists](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/practical-statistics-for/9781491952955/) book (p.218/247 e2).

**BACKGROUND:**

- I'm working on a rare-class/imbalanced dataset
- I used [SMOTE](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1813) (Synthetic Minority Over-sampling Technique) to balance my model (and scale to normalize) and have obtained sufficient results
- example code (high level idea; see [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIC5f.png) for code):

```
    knn (
        train = scale(sample(smote(dataset)))),
        test = scale(1-sample(smote(dataset)))),
        cl = 1-sample(smote(dataset))),
        ...
    )
```

- I want to use the output probabilities in ensemble learning

[Image1-Model working with SMOTE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIC5f.png)

**ISSUE:**

- I want to make predictions with the high performance KNN model above, however, when I apply it to the base dataset, the output doesn't classify anything (i.e., everything is a zero versus zero & one) ([Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TYmb.png))

[Image2-SMOTE model does not work with base data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TYmb.png)

**Note:**

1. I used a similar pattern to the O'Reilly book, where KNN functions over the base dataset in train, test, and CL parameters ([Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KJuO.png))
2. I selected the appropriate range to match the SMOTE dataset so there were no 'train' & 'Class' errors -- the range also has sufficient distribution values (i.e., same distribution as normal)

[Image3-BookReference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KJuO.png)

Not sure what to do as I have a high performant model with SMOTE, but now those values aren't able to tie back to the original dataset. It's almost like I want to UN-SMOTE after classification in order to use the attributes with the base data. That or tie everything with left joins, etc.

I would expect that I could take the SMOTE dataset, and use that to predict over a valid test dataset. However, it did not work. I've tried everything, formatting columns, scaling/unscaling, SMOTE and not SMOTE, Updating the SMOTE dataset to have similar row size, etc.

**POST EDIT**
Below is a reproduceable script to see the issue.

Image 4.1 is the output with a 'standard' KNN model
[Image 4.1 - Original KNN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIeAR.png)

Image 4.2 is the output with a SMOTE KNN model
[Image 4.2 - SMOTE KNN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHI6F.png)

Image 4.3 is the output with the SMOTE KNN model over the original Dataset
[Image 4.3 - SMOTE Model and Original Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGrHi.png)

**WORKING KNN FOR STANDARD/SMOTE**

```r
## DataPrep
  set.seed(0)
  df <- data.frame(y=rep(as.factor(c('Yes', 'No')), times=c(90, 10)),x1=rnorm(100),x2=rnorm(100))
  df_knn <- 
          smote(y~x1+x2,data=df,perc.over = 4, perc.under = 1.25 ) ##Smote - 50/50 split
          # df ##Standard
## Split data & Scale
  sample_size = floor(0.8*nrow(df_knn))
  split = sample(seq_len(nrow(df_knn)),size = sample_size)
    train_cl = df_knn[split,]
    test_cl = df_knn[-split,]
  ## Scale data
    train_scale <- scale( select ( train_cl, x1, x2) )
    test_scale <-  scale( select ( test_cl, x1, x2) )
## KNN - Best K Inserted from below
  classifier_knn <- knn(
          train = train_scale,
                    test = test_scale,
                    cl = train_cl[,"y"] ,
          prob = TRUE,
                    k = 15)
## Confusion Matrix & Metrics
  cm <- table(test_cl$y, classifier_knn)
  cm
  print(paste('Accuracy =', round( (cm[1,1]+cm[2,2]) / sum(cm[]), digits = 4) * 100 ))
  print(paste('Precision =',round( cm[2,2] / sum(cm[,2]), digits = 4)* 100 ))
  print(paste('Specificity =', round( cm[1,1] / sum(cm[1,]), digits = 4)* 100 ))
  print(paste('Recall =', round( cm[2,2] / sum(cm[2,]), digits = 4)* 100 ))
```

**KNN MODEL NOT WORKING OVER ORIGINAL DATA**

```r
## DataPrep
  set.seed(0)
  df <- data.frame(y=rep(as.factor(c('Yes', 'No')), times=c(90, 10)),x1=rnorm(100),x2=rnorm(100))
  df_knn <- smote(y~x1+x2,data=df,perc.over = 4, perc.under = 1.25 ) ##Smote - 50/50 split
## Split data & Scale
  sample_size = floor(0.8*nrow(df_knn))
  split = sample(seq_len(nrow(df_knn)),size = sample_size)
    train_cl = df_knn[split,]
    test_cl = df_knn[-split,]
  ## Scale data
    train_scale <- scale( select ( train_cl, x1, x2) )
    test_scale <-  scale( select ( test_cl, x1, x2) )
## KNN - Best K Inserted from below
  classifier_knn <- knn( train_scale, test = train_scale, cl = df[split,'y'] , prob = TRUE, k = 15)
## Original Dataset & Distribution
  table( df[split,'y'] )
## Train Dataset & Distribution 
  table( train_cl$y)
## KNN Output
  table ( classifier_knn )
```

Answer (score 0):

Beyond impressed with ChatGPT as I navigated this problem! Certainly, the program unstuck me; attached are two critical responses.

[ChatGPT Response 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtsgZ.png)

[ChatGPT Response 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uHDV.png)

My key take aways were:

1. Train & Class parameters of KNN need not only be of the same length, but ideally should be of the same dataset. Train containing independent (predictor) values and Class containing the dependent (predicted) value.
2. Test can then be your evaluating dataset. In this case, to optimize SMOTE and SCALE, I SMOTED and scaled the training dataset (see above) and then evaluated against a scaled version of the original dataset.

The full code is below.

The accuracy of this model is pretty good compared to the model over training data (which in turn is SUBSTANCIALLY) better than the model over the standard/unSMOTE dataset. Images below.

[Model: Prediction over Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXbD7.png)

[Model: Prediction over Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeU66.png)

In summary. This was very thought provoking and I hope this will help someone else in the future. Cheers!

```r
## Packages Required
  # install.packages('pacman') 
  library('pacman')
    pacman::p_load(RODBC, dplyr, FNN, performanceEstimation, corrplot)

## DataPrep
  set.seed(0)
  df <- data.frame(y=rep(as.factor(c('0', '1')), times=c(90, 10)),x1=rnorm(100),x2=rnorm(100))

## Split, SMOTE, & Scale
  # SPLIT
    sample_size = floor(0.8*nrow(df))
    split = sample(seq_len(nrow(df)),size = sample_size)
      train_cl = df[split,]
      test_cl = df[-split,]
  # SMOTE: 1/2 < 1/3 < 1/5 > 1/10
    train_cl_smote <- smote(y~x1+x2,data=train_cl,perc.over = 1, perc.under = 8 ) 
  ## SCALE
    train_scale <- scale( select ( train_cl_smote, x1, x2) )
    test_scale <-  scale( select ( test_cl, x1, x2) )
    df_scale <- scale(select(df, x1, x2))
  
## KNN - Best K Inserted from below
  classifier_knn <- knn(
        train = train_cl_smote[,-1],
                test = df_scale , 
                cl = train_cl_smote[,1],
        prob = TRUE,
                k = 3)
  
  cm <- table(df$y, classifier_knn)
  cm
    Accuracy <- round( (cm[1,1]+cm[2,2]) / sum(cm[]), digits = 4) * 100 
    Precision <- round( cm[2,2] / sum(cm[,2]), digits = 4)* 100 
    Specificity <- round( cm[1,1] / sum(cm[1,]), digits = 4)* 100 
    Recall <- round( cm[2,2] / sum(cm[2,]), digits = 4)* 100 
    FScore <- round ( ( (Precision * Recall ) / (Precision + Recall ) ), digits = 2 )
  print(  paste( 'Accuracy=', Accuracy , '% | Precision=' , Precision , '% | Specificity=' , Specificity , '% | Recall=' , Recall , '% | FScore=', FScore , '%') )

## This can now be applied back to the model, e.g., df$pred <- classifier_knn
```